# Error creating Vector Image Asset: <text> is not supported

Tags: android, android-studio, svg

I created a basic SVG file in illustrator using Line Tool, Eclipse Tool & Text only. The font I used was Century Schoolbook.

When I try to configure a vector asset I get the error,  is not supported. The preview shows the SVG without the text

Am I not suppose to use text on SVG files? Surely that can't be the case?

Here's the error:

[image]

Comment: "Am I not suppose to use text on SVG files?" -- AFAIK, yes. Android's vector assets only support a subset of SVG, and AFAIK that does not include text. I imagine the issue is the availability of the font. I don't use Illustrator, put it might have an option to convert text to paths.

Comment: @CommonsWare - Thanks, I'll look at converting & report back.

Comment: @CommonsWare - It worked, if you want to post that as an answer, ill accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At present, Android's vector assets handle a small subset of SVG, mostly focused on paths. It does not appear that it supports text.

However, your SVG tool may have the ability to export an SVG where the text (in your desired font) is converted to paths. This also ensures that your text shows up in your desired (converted) font, as the font you might be using in your artwork may not exist on the Android device.